# Force IIS to reload URL Rewrite Rules

Tags: url-rewriting, iis

I did a change to the URL Rewrite rules to prevent hotlinking to pictures and uploaded the Rules.Config to my site.  However, it didn't work so I rolled the change back and reload web.config.

However, the rule which is wrong is still being "employed" by IIS, its as if IIS isn't re-reading the rule.  How do I force IIS to re-read the rules, it didn't the first time but not now.

I'm on a shared server.

Comment: Do an IIS reset as the administrator

Comment: Don't have access to IISReset, am on Shared Server.  Been shown how to do it in Plesk instead for future now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These changes should take effect immediately. Try restarting the website from the IIS Manager.

Comment: THats what I thought but after contacting support, note, am on shared server so couldn't do it myself.  They showed me how to restart the Application Pool via Plesk.

Answer (score 1):

Those changes should apply instantly. Maybe what's happening to you is an effect of the client-side cache of the browser.

If you had already downloaded the images before establishing the new rule, they are cached by default and the rule doesn't seem to work, but it's working.

Try to reload the image with CTRL+R instead of simply revisiting their URL, and it should work.